# How to remove particular history from zsh-history

Tags: zsh

I want to remove the entry 9280 from my history.

How to do it?

```
8850  rake schedule:parser
8859  zeus rake schedule:parser
9280  rm -rf /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.Trash/img /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.Trash/custom.css\ 15-52-37-010.scss /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.Trash/application.html.haml /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.Trash/Recovered\ files\ \#95 /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.Trash/untitled\ folder\ 1.38.05\ PM /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.Trash/Recovered\ fil
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it from the $HISTFILE.